# Unable to create a "Query type" in data set that returns multiple rows

Tags: asp.net, dataset

Why might I not be able to select the option "SELECT which returns rows" from this list when creating a brand new DataSet?

[image]

My connection string looks like this:

```
<add name="WareHouse"
     connectionString="Data Source=******Initial Catalog=E-WareHouse;User Id=******;password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=******"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I am also using Visual Studio 2015 Community which may be a factor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a TableAdapter before adding specific queries

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04y282hb.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396